# Updating prod database after reverting and adding migrations in dev

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm running an asp.net core app with ef core and two environments: prod and dev. I created some migrations and applied them to both environments a while ago, but needed to roll them back in development. After I rolled back in dev, I kept developing and now have many migrations in dev that are not in prod, as well as the reverted migrations in prod that I haven't rolled back yet. So now my environment's migrations look like this:

`Prod => a,b,c,d`

`Dev  => a,b,e,f,g`

> (one major thing to note: the migrations i'm reverting in prod (c,d)
>   are not being used, they were just models I created for
>   future use - that I ended up changing - so loss of data from these
>   migrations is not a concern)

I can't run the same commands I ran initially in dev since i'm not adding any migrations now, I just need to update the prod database to the migrations I have locally.

If I `update-database b` then `update-database` will this revert the changes in prod then update to my local migrations? Or will this revert the migrations i've added in visual studio? What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the production environment run a downgrade to the latest working migration:

```
Update-Database –Migration b
```

Then delete the 2 migrations **c** and **d** from your migration folder.

Finally you can update to the latest migration on the production enviroment:

```
Update-Database
```

Comment: I realized after the fact that I could just switch to my master branch, revert the few migrations, then switch to my dev branch and update-database from there.